# Cocoa: Key down event on NSView not firing

Tags: cocoa, keydown, document-based

I have made a custom NSView and have implemented the `keyDown:` method. However, when I press keys the method is never called. Do I have to register to receive those events? fyi, I am making a document based application and can handle this code anywhere (doesn't have to be in this view). What is the best place to do this in a document based application such that the event will occur throughout the entire application?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You need to override `-acceptsFirstResponder` to return `YES`.

Comment: I have the same problem as the asker (custom NSView in a document-based application), and just overrided acceptsFirstResponder but keyDown is still not triggered. If you have any other advice as to what it could be I would be eternally grateful!

Comment: Do you have reason to believe that your view is the window's first responder?  You can set the `initialFirstResponder` in code before the window is ordered on screen or connect it in IB.  At other times, you can use `-makeFirstResponder:`.  Also, make sure your window can become key.

Answer (score 10):

In Swift:

```
class MDView: NSView {
    override var acceptsFirstResponder: Bool { return true }
}
```